# Return paths in 2D array from list of sequences in python

Tags: python, arrays, search, networkx

I am trying to find all possible paths from a list of sequences in a 2D array. For example, in the 2D array:

```
test_array = np.array([['f', 'l', 'p'],
                       ['r', 'a', 'o'],
                       ['b', 'o', 'd']])
```

for the given path: `test_seqs = ['lao']`

I have created an indexed array of unique indices:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
```

What I need, is to return the possible paths of: `[[1,4,5],[1,4,7]]`

This is the simplest example, but I eventually have a 14 x 14 grid. My current solution which uses Networkx and all_simple_paths simply creates too many paths that it explodes in this large array configuration. My idea was to start at `1`, check the neighbors and return `4`, check this neighbors returning `[5,7]` at which point it reaches the end of the sequence and then returns the result. Alternatively, it would start at `1`, go to `4` and then `5` after checking the neighbors, and then repeat; start at `1`, go to `4` and then go to `7` since that one is not visited.

My current attempt traverses it once outputting `[1,4,5,7,5,4,7]` rather than the two separate instances.
Here is the full code, I am using Networkx since I had it implemented previously and using it to check neighbors. Note: There is no option to specify the path in Networkx, you can give a list of end values for all_simple_paths but this explodes the number of possible paths. In the 14 x 14 array case, with a sequence of 9 it never finished going through all options. It does work fine for small sequences.

Here is the code I have with 2 test cases, 1 of which is correct when there is only 1 path available (no branching):

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import copy


class EndOfPath(Exception):
    """Raised for end of path"""
    pass


def set_node_labels(G, arr):
    values = arr.flatten()
    labels = {}
    for node in G.nodes():
        labels[node] = values[node]
    nx.set_node_attributes(G, labels, "label")
    return labels


def get_neighbors(s, last_letters_idx, path):
    last_letters_idx = last_letters_idx[last_letters_idx != s]

    if len(last_letters_idx) == 0:
        raise EndOfPath("end of path")
    neighbors = []
    for n in G.neighbors(s):
        neighbors.append(n)
    possible_neighbors = last_letters_idx[np.where(np.isin(last_letters_idx, neighbors))]

    for n in possible_neighbors:
        path.append(n)
        get_neighbors(n, last_letters_idx, path)


def get_possible_seq(seq, idx_array, letter_array, G):
    found_seqs = []
    found_sqs_loc = []
    first_letter = seq[0]
    last_letters = seq[1:]
    first_letter_idx = idx_array[np.where(letter_array == first_letter)]
    last_letters_idx = []
    for letters in last_letters:
        last_letters_idx.extend(idx_array[np.where(letter_array == [letter for letter in letters])])
    last_letters_idx = np.array(last_letters_idx)

    paths = []
    for s in first_letter_idx:
        # correction for double counting on start letter position
        path = [s]
        try:
            get_neighbors(s, last_letters_idx, path)
        except EndOfPath:
            paths.append(path)

    print(f'paths{paths}')
    for path in paths:
        string = []
        for node in path:
            string.extend(G.nodes[node]['label'])
        found_seqs.append(string)
        found_sqs_loc.append(path)
    return found_seqs, found_sqs_loc


test_array = np.array([['f', 'l', 'p'],
                       ['r', 'a', 'o'],
                       ['b', 'o', 'd']])

test_seqs = ['lao', 'rad']

W,H = test_array.shape

index_array = np.arange(0, len(test_array.ravel()), 1, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((W,H))
print(index_array)

node_connections = []
for j in range(H-1):
    for i in range(W-1):
        n1 = (index_array[j, i], index_array[j, i+1])
        n2 = (index_array[j, i], index_array[(j+1), i])
        n3 = (index_array[j, i], index_array[(j+1), i+1])

        node_connections.extend([n1, n2, n3])
    n4 = (index_array[j, W-1], index_array[(j + 1), W-1])
    node_connections.extend([n4])

# create graph
G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(node_connections)

labels = set_node_labels(G, test_array)
seq_locations_dict = {}
for test_seq in test_seqs:
    print(test_seq)
    found_seqs, found_seqs_loc = get_possible_seq(test_seq, index_array, test_array, G)
    print(found_seqs)
    run = True
    found_seq_tmp = copy.deepcopy(found_seqs)
    found_seq_loc_tmp = copy.deepcopy(found_seqs_loc)
    flag = 0
    seq_locations_dict[test_seq] = []
    # run through all paths returned, keep all correct sequences
    while run:
        try:
            target_seq_idx = found_seq_tmp.index(list(test_seq))
            seq_locations_dict[test_seq].append(found_seq_loc_tmp[target_seq_idx])
            found_seq_tmp.pop(target_seq_idx)
            found_seq_loc_tmp.pop(target_seq_idx)
            flag = 1
        except ValueError:
            if flag == 1:
                print(f'No more to find of target word \"{test_seq}\".')
            else:
                print(f'Cannot find target word \"{test_seq}\".')
                del seq_locations_dict[test_seq]
            run = False
print(seq_locations_dict)
# should return {'lao': [[1,4,5], [1,4,7], 'rad':[[3,4,8]}
```

EDIT: There is a discussion on Reddit which I have got some nice solutions to. Here is the link:
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/j2u6ea/return_paths_in_2d_array_from_list_of_sequences/

Comment: I think networkx may be overkill for this. I'd try defining a class with a recursive neighbor-searching method. A class is helpful because some of this information needs to persist between searches

Comment: @Michael thanks for the suggestion. Would you have any pseudo-code or resource to get me started? What do you mean by persist between searches? I don't have a CS background so have just been winging this